# Twilio API - Retrieve all recording of a incoming number (Twilio voice number)

Tags: twilio, voice-recording

I have several Twilio numbers under one account.
What I am trying to do is, I need to get all previously recorded files from Twilio per Twilio number (voice number).
My code is below, please correct me if I did something wrong.

```
$records = $client->account->recordings->getIterator(0, 50, array(
    "DateCreated" => "2015-11-20<",
    "Callsid" => $call_sid
));
```

As you might expect, this returns nothing.
I have tried without setting dates and that returns the whole data under my account.

I read another post and it suggested that the parameters for queries are case sensitive, but that did not help me though. ([Twilio API getting the recording of a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055523/twilio-api-getting-the-recording-of-a-call))
I am not sure what I did wrong.
Can anyone point out what fails?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Jae, hello! It's Megan from Twilio here.

Sometimes it's the little things, but I believe you just have a typo having added `<` to `DateCreated`.

Instead it should simply be, `"DateCreated" => "2015-11-20"`
You can see some more examples [in PHP here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording).

Let me know if that does the trick!

Comment: Hi Megan, without DateCreated should work but that does not work.

Comment: Megan, I actually do not get any and I realized that CallSid was not what I thought it is. I needed to filter by SId (Phone number Sid).

Comment: Ah okay, then this might be more useful for you. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers